# How to generate unique numbers into a textbox and multiply the numbers in another textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html:

```
<input name="code" type="text" id="box" /><input id = "button" type="button" value="Create Random String"><br />
```

here is my jquery for generating strings:

```
var o = { // Define Letter Values
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
};
$('#button').on("click", function(){
var chars = "123456789";
var string_length = 8;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}
//document.randform.code.value = randomstring;
//document.code.value = randomstring;
  $('#box').val(randomstring);
      $( "#value" ).val(function() {
     var str = $(this).val();       
var arr = split('');        
var total = 0;
$.each(arr, function(i, v){     
    var letterIndex = o[v];     
    if(i === 0){                
        total = letterIndex;
    } else {                    
        total = total * letterIndex;
    }

  });
```

the question is, how do I generate strings in the `#box` textbox and multiply the numbers generated in the `#value` textbox at the same time?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Comment: Your array `arr` is always empty.

Comment: please, i do not have that at the moment.

Comment: The `var arr = split(''); ` is incorrect syntax. http://jsfiddle.net/akvabtdp/ . The split must be called for an string

Comment: @ Alireza Fattahi thanks alot...please how can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can apply the code from this snippet. It

- creates 10 pseudorandom 10-digit number pairs
- multiplies the number pairs
- shows the result

```js
var result = document.querySelector('pre');
var n = 10;

while (n--) {
  var r1 = randomNumber(10);
  var r2 = randomNumber(10);
  var r3 = r1 * r2;
  result.textContent += '\n' + r1+' * '+r2 + ' = ' + r3;
}

function randomNumber(len) {
  var digit = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9);
  var n1    = (Math.pow(10, len-1)) * digit;
  var n2    = n1/10;
  return Math.floor(n1+Math.random() * n2 - 1);
}
```

```html
<pre>testing numbers</pre>
```